# I can't take the information of my result of fetch. Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

When I try to take the result of my API I can't.
my code:

```
export async function validLoginFetch(email,password){

    const data = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    let headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
  
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body:data,
      headers:headers,
    }

    return await fetch('http://localhost:1323/profile/valid', options).then(response => {return response.json()})
}
```

the code that calls the function

```
    async function validateLogin() {
       if (password !== "" && email !== "") {
          const response = await validLoginFetch(email, password)
          console.log(response)
      }
    };
```

the full code:

```
import '../App.css';
import { validLoginFetch } from '../api/user'
import React , { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default () => {

  const [email, setEmail]  = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword]  = useState("");
  const [validUser, setValidUser]  = useState(false);

async function validateLogin() {
   if (password !== "" && email !== "") {
      const response = await validLoginFetch(email, password)
      console.log(response)
  }
};

  useEffect(()=> {
    if (validUser){
      //useNavigate("/#");

    }
  
  });


  return (
    <div className="login">
      <form onSubmit={validateLogin}>
        <div>
          <span>email</span>
          <input
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder=""
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>password</span>
          <input
            onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            id="password"
            name="password"
            placeholder=""
          />
        </div>
        <button
          onSubmit={validLoginFetch}
          id="authenticate-user-login"
          className="authenticate-user-login"
        >
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
);

}
```

not return anything. My route works fine. The problem isn't in the backend.

if I try to delete the async and await, the return is a Promise. If I use the async and await did never return anything. it stays in the `validLoginFetch` and doesn't continue.
Does someone know what it can be?

Comment: Your `validateLogin()` function does not have a `return` statement, so of course it does not return anything.

Comment: Did you check the network tab in the browser? What does it say? Is the request made? Does it return? Is it successful?

Comment: but i use the console.log(response) and it don't print anything in my console.... I don't want return the response, I just want to use the value ... but I will do this later, for now I need to know if i have a value in return of my fetch.....

Comment: What are the values of `password` and `email` when that function runs?

Comment: the values that I pass in form, that is teste@gmail.com and password teste.

Comment: @vlaz I see in my backend, and when I call the function works fine, and return for me the value that I want , I see it in my backend, in front return me the state of 204, how if it don't have any return. I don't know what happend in the front that not return me this value.

Comment: @VLAZ this is what have in the route in my networking.  Request URL: http://localhost:1323/profile/valid
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: [::1]:1323
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Status code 204 No Content is pretty clear - your backend isn't returning anything.

Comment: What is the Content-Type of the HTTP response?

Comment: @MikeM but when I hit in curl It return me a value. I don't know what it's happen

Comment: @thgaskell 'the value return a string, so if I put in header that content-type is apllication/json and i return a string, the function don't will recognize the value? I need to return the value as json in the backend?

Comment: Are you sure that the `if (password !== "" && email !== "")` condition is passing? (To shorten this discussion, please delete your comments addressed to me above, except your last one.)

Comment: @MikeM yes I have sure, in the backend when I click in the button shows me the values in the password and email, and I saw in others ways the values that bring of password and email, it's all fine.

Comment: @ElisaSouza yes. If you are using Express, make sure to use [`res.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) on the backend

Comment: @thgaskell hey!, my api is in go lang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finded the answer.... we need to refresh the form before send it to fetch... so The problem was the time for refreshing the form, we need to refreshing before send it. To solve this, set to refresh the form on response:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

in my case:

resolve put these command before called the function that make the fetch:

```
async function validateLogin() {
   event.preventDefault();
   if (password !== "" && email !== "") {
      const response = await validLoginFetch(email, password)
      console.log(response)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ASYNC/AWAIT or THEN, not both at the same time.

Try this:

```
export async function validLoginFetch(email,password){

    const data = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    let headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
  
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body:data,
      headers:headers,
    }

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1323/profile/valid', options);
    const json = await response.json();

    return json; 
}
```

Comment: still don't print anything when i try to do console.log(response) in function validateLogin()

Comment: @ElisaSouza this is because the answer is wrong. There is no technical problem with mixing async/await and promise API. The practice is not *recommended* but by no means forbidden. It's not recommended because it might lead to confusion in how the code operates. But swapping `p.then(x => x.foo())` to `x = await p; await x.foo()` does not change any operation at all.

Comment: @ElisaSouza try to check the network tab like VLAZ said.

Comment: @Ali Shadman, yes I answered him:   this what have in the route in my networking. Request URL: localhost:1323/profile/valid Request Method: OPTIONS Status Code: 204 No Content Remote Address: [::1]:1323 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin